# Prove: $|f(z)| ≤ \frac{2A|z|}{1−|z|}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disc $\{z : |z| < 1\}$ satisfying $f(0) = 0$ and $Ref(z) ≤ A$ for some positive number $A > 0.$ Prove:
$|f(z)| ≤ \frac{2A|z|}{1−|z|}$.

Not sure how to do this problem.  Thinking Schwartz but can't think of anything.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you map the half-plane to the unit disk?

Comment: Yea but how does this help?

Comment: It puts you in the situation where Schwarz' lemma applies directly.

Comment: *Follow this scheme*: The image of $f$ is half space. Transform it to a unit disk. Then apply Schwartz' lemma.